# How to return tuple with IEnumerable<(string category, IEnumerable<Product> productsName)> with linq

Tags: c#, linq, tuples, yield-return

Well I have to return result in tuple's format, but because of nested foreach loops, i can't use yield return (tuple). What should i do?

```
public static IEnumerable<(string category, IEnumerable<Product> productsName)> GroupJoinQuery()
{
            string[] categories =
            {
                "Vegetables",
                "Dairy Products",
                "Seafood"
            };

            List<Product> products = Products.ProductList;

            var q = categories.GroupJoin(products, c => c, p => p.Category, (c, ps)
=> new { Category = c, Products = ps });

            foreach (var v in q)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{v.Category}:");
                foreach (var p in v.Products)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"   {p.ProductName}");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yield return can easily be replaced with adding to a list as you loop, and then returning the list. Start with `var results = new List<Product> productsName)>();` and add `return results;` after the loops, going `results.Add((v.Category, v.Products));` at each iteration of the outer loop; the inner loop doesn't seem to be needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you wish to return one element per category, with the second component of the tuple being an `IEnumerable` of products matching the category, the following will work fine:

```
public static IEnumerable<(string category, IEnumerable<Product> productsName)> GroupJoinQuery()
{
    string[] categories =
    {
                "Vegetables",
                "Dairy Products",
                "Seafood"
            };

    List<Product> products = Products.ProductList;

    return (IEnumerable<(string category, IEnumerable<Product> productsName)>) 
        categories.GroupJoin(products, c => c, p => p.Category, (c, ps)
        => new { Category = c, Products = ps.ToArray() });
}
```

Note the use of `ToArray()`. If `products` is ultimately populated by a database and the `IEnumerable` is iterated after a required context is disposed, you would get a runtime exception. The call to `ToArray()` materializes the result (copies it to memory). For modest result sizes, this is an acceptable strategy. If the result set is substantial, you may wish to consider a different approach.

Comment: Why exactly do we need the yield return, does `return categories.GroupJoin(products, c => c, p => p.Category, (c, ps) => (c, ps));` not work?

Comment: Indeed, that's a more compact solution (though a cast is required due to the .ToArray() invocation).

Comment: I think problem of original question and this answer that you return anonymous object instead of Tuple.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv No, the returned value certainly matches the function signature (tested it in LinqPAD to be certain).

Comment: `new { Category = c, Products = ps.ToArray() }` is not Tuple. Cast should fail. Or I have missed some C# automatic conversion.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv: And yet, the cast in fact succeeds. Give it a try.